# Shadow rate on UITableViewCell contenview increasing while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

In my app, I'm using dynamic height cells using auto layout. So for creating cardview effect I've to use tableview willdisplaycell method. It only add shadow only once to cell. But I don't know why shadow increasing while scrolling.

Here's my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //setup card view style on cell
        if !cellArray.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, width: cell.contentView.frame.size.width-10, height: cell.contentView.frame.size.height-10))
            whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
            whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
            whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
            cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)
            cellArray.add(indexPath.row)
        }
    }
```

Comment: The widely accepted way of doing this is subclassing your cell, and adding the rounded view in the cell's `awakeFromNib`, or within the `xib` file, unless there is some really intricate edge case you need to handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this piece of line is the causing the issue.

> cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)

whenever **willDisplayCell** gets called, you will be adding the view everytime. That is the reason shadow is getting increased while scrolling. The solution is,

```
1. check the cell content view if the view is already added or not. If not, then add the view. use view tag to do it.

2. otherwise, create a shadow view and initialize the specific things in the -(void)awakeFromNib, which will get called only once.
```

**but personally, i prefer option 2, which will isolate your view render logic from view controller or cell.**

add the below code to your custom cell class. In this case, i have given leading-trialing-top-bottom constraints as 15-15-15-15. If you wish you can set it to 0. but make sure that it should in sync with the background constraints.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, width: contentView.frame.size.width-10, height: contentView.frame.size.height-10))
    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    whiteRoundedView.tag = shadowTag
    whiteRoundedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)
    let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: whiteRoundedView,
                                     attribute: .leading,
                                     relatedBy: .equal,
                                     toItem: contentView,
                                     attribute: .leading,
                                     multiplier: 1.0,
                                     constant: 15.0)
    let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: whiteRoundedView,
                                      attribute: .trailing,
                                      relatedBy: .equal,
                                      toItem: contentView,
                                      attribute: .trailing,
                                      multiplier: 1.0,
                                      constant: -15.0)

    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: whiteRoundedView,
                                 attribute: .top,
                                 relatedBy: .equal,
                                 toItem: contentView,
                                 attribute: .top,
                                 multiplier: 1.0,
                                 constant: 15.0)

    let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: whiteRoundedView,
                                    attribute: .bottom,
                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                    toItem: contentView,
                                    attribute: .bottom,
                                    multiplier: 1.0,
                                    constant: -15.0)

    contentView.addConstraint(leading)
    contentView.addConstraint(trailing)
    contentView.addConstraint(top)
    contentView.addConstraint(bottom)
}
```

**Ref screenshot :** 
[image]

Comment: I checked with breakpoint and i'm sure that, "cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)" this code only execute once for a cell . But when i use ths code in -(void)awakeFromNib it shows shadow with intial size of cell, not with dynamic size. means shadow size is not changing with cell dynamic size

Comment: when you are adding the subview, please mention the auto layout to the view. let shadowView = ShadowView() . add auto layout constraints to shadowView -> cell.contentView. make it 0-0-0-0 from left-top-bottom-right.

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it out

Comment: Wow. It fixed my issues. Adding shadow view with autolayout fixed all issues. Thanks man :)

Comment: Where do you set shadowTag? And what do you set shadowTag to?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your code here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: <idenitfier>, for: indexPath) as? JobListTableViewCell

    if cell == nil {

        //Initialization and setting of shadow

    }
    return cell 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: xcode shows warning "Comparing non-optional value of type 'JobListTableViewCell' to nil always returns false", so i think this is not useful

Comment: I tried with your updated code but it is not useful when using dynamic height cells.